# how to pass value of a variable from javascript to rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new to rails, please help me out.

This is my javascript i want `filename` value to be passed in the controller `page_controller` to the `create_table` action

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#prefix, #client, #myFile").change(function(){
    concatenated_string = $("#prefix").val() + "_" + $("#client").val() + "_" + $("#myFile").val();
    $("#concatenated_string").val(concatenated_string);
     myvar = concatenated_string.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
     myvar = myvar.replace(/\..+$/, '');
     myvar = myvar.replace(/\s+/, "_");

     var filename = myvar //This variable

    $("#temp_display").text(filename)

 })
})
```

This below file is my `page_controller.rb` and the `create_table` action

```
class PageController < ApplicationController

  # before_action :authenticate_user!
  #before_action :set_company, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index]

  def home
  end


  def titlebar
  end


 def insert_table
  #redirect_to :action => "create_table"
 end 

  def create_table

            filename = params[:filename]

  end  
end
```

This is what am getting in terminal

```
    Started POST "/page/create_table" for ::1 at 2017-01-28 20:45:05 +0530
Processing by PageController#create_table as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TAcnZfhr8Amg8/xupgJVlAosz+/hNPgFgxVT4cg5x+OKvRwvrtm6Z5momvQiHsYBcl1tZWUu525Z1VTxqWIu8Q==", "commit"=>"upload file"}
  Rendering page/create_table.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered page/create_table.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 190ms (Views: 186.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: What `#temp_display` refers to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution .

this is my js

```
function myFunction()
{
    concatenated_string = $("#prefix").val() + "_" + $("#client").val()     + "_" + $("#myFile").val();
 $("#concatenated_string").val(concatenated_string);
 myvar = concatenated_string.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
 myvar = myvar.replace(/\..+$/, '');
 myvar = myvar.replace(/\s+/, "_");

 var filename = myvar;

$("#temp_display").text(filename);
document.getElementById("my_file_name").value = filename;  
}
```

this is in my view as suggested by pavan

```
<input type="hidden" name="filename" id="my_file_name" value="">
```

this is my controller

```
  def create_table
        filename = params[:filename]
        content = params[:file].path
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a ***hidden input field*** in the form like below for which the ***filename*** value can be appended, so that you can capture the value in the `create_table` action.

```
#in your form
<input type="hidden" name="filename" id="my_file_name" value="">
```

And in script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#prefix, #client, #myFile").change(function(){
    concatenated_string = $("#prefix").val() + "_" + $("#client").val() + "_" + $("#myFile").val();
    $("#concatenated_string").val(concatenated_string);
     myvar = concatenated_string.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
     myvar = myvar.replace(/\..+$/, '');
     myvar = myvar.replace(/\s+/, "_");

     var filename = myvar //This variable

    $("#temp_display").text(filename);
    $("#my_file_name").val() = filename; //Add this line

 })
})
```

Now, you can capture the value of ***filename*** with `params[:filename]`.

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cIBAaWKbIXKisAnQgnfZUeHWXkYAbfKXS9CBEGugItK2OnsjNClrHJvrb0oGa0rEmaf8zIR37fyREIYACvvLwA==", "filename"=>"", "commit"=>"upload file"}

@pavan filename is nil am getting this in terminal

Comment: @SagarRS Try inspecting filename value in the console with `console.log(filename);`